# UTF-8 conversion to real letter

Tags: python, python-3.x, utf

I need help with one of my projects. I'm cleaning a large set of data to bulk insert into microsoft SQL. The data is like 10million lines. But I created a script just to extract the first 1000 for cleaning assuming the rest are the same. I noticed there was a lot of UTF-8 characters, so I converted it to the nearest real character. But after I extracted it to view the first 100000 lines, I noticed there is way more UTF-8 conversions that needs to be done and i'm converting them manually which is pretty exhaustive. I was wondering if there was an easier way to do this rather than manually entering everything in. Here is my code:

```
import re

infile = r"C:\\Users\\Dave\\Desktop\\database\\page-links_en.txt"
outfile = r"C:\\Users\\Dave\\Desktop\\database\\Complete\\cleanedpagelinks_file.txt"

fin = open(infile)
fout = open(outfile, "w+")

rex = re.compile(r'/([^/>]+)>')

for line in fin:
#for word in delete_list:
#    line = line.replace(word, "")
line = line.replace("%C3%A9","e")
line = line.replace("%C3%B3","o")
line = line.replace("%E2%80%93","-")
line = line.replace("%C3%A6","e")
line = line.replace("%C3%A8","e")
line = line.replace("_"," ")
line = line.replace("%C3%A0","e")
line = line.replace("%C3%A1","i")
line = line.replace("%C5%82","l")
line = line.replace("%C5%84","n")
line = line.replace("%C3%BF", "y")
line = line.replace("%C3%BE", "p")
line = line.replace("%C3%BD", "y")
line = line.replace("%C3%BC", "u")
line = line.replace("%C3%BB", "u")
line = line.replace("%C3%BA", "u")
line = line.replace("%C3%B9", "o")
line = line.replace("%C3%B6", "o")
line = line.replace("%C3%B5", "o")
line = line.replace("%C3%B4", "o")
line = line.replace("%C3%B3", "o")
line = line.replace("%C3%B2", "o")
line = line.replace("%C3%B1", "n")
line = line.replace("%C3%B0", "e")
line = line.replace("%C3%AC", "i")
line = line.replace("%C3%AD", "i")
line = line.replace("%C3%AE", "i")
line = line.replace("%C3%AF", "i")
line = line.replace("%C3%81","A")
line = line.replace("%C3%82","A")
line = line.replace("%C3%83","A")
line = line.replace("%C3%84","A")
line = line.replace("%C3%85","A")
line = line.replace("%C3%86","AE")
line = line.replace("%C3%87","C")
line = line.replace("%C3%88","E")
line = line.replace("%C3%89","E")
line = line.replace("%C3%8A","E")
line = line.replace("%C3%8B","E")
line = line.replace("%C3%8C","I")
line = line.replace("%C3%8D","I")
line = line.replace("%C3%8E","I")
line = line.replace("%C3%8F","I")
line = line.replace("%C3%90","D")
line = line.replace("%C3%91","N")
line = line.replace("%C3%92","O")
line = line.replace("%C3%93","O")
line = line.replace("%C3%94","O")
line = line.replace("%C3%95","O")
line = line.replace("%C3%96","O")
line = line.replace("%C3%98","O")
line = line.replace("%C3%99","U")
line = line.replace("%C3%9A","U")
line = line.replace("%C3%9B","U")
line = line.replace("%C3%9C","U")
line = line.replace("%C3%9D","Y")
line = line.replace("%C3%9F","B")
line = line.replace("%C3%a0","a")
line = line.replace("%C3%a1","a")
line = line.replace("%C3%a2","a")
line = line.replace("%C3%a3","a")
line = line.replace("%C3%a4","a")
line = line.replace("%C3%a5","a")
line = line.replace("%C3%a6","ae")
line = line.replace("%C3%a7","c")
line = line.replace("%C3%a8","e")
line = line.replace("%C3%a9","e")
line = line.replace("%C3%aa","e")
line = line.replace("%C3%ab","e")


match = rex.search(line)
if match:
    newline = match.group(1)
else: newline = ''
fout.write(newline + '\n')
fin.close()
fout.close()
```

As you can see in my code I'm manually replacing to the real character value.
Here's an example line in my text file that I realized needs to be converted.

```
B%E1%BA%A3o %C4%90%E1%BA%A1i
```

Comment: can you give the part of file for test? or try to use the line.decode('utf-8').encode('iso-8859-1')

Comment: What is the encoding of the input and what should the encoding of the output be?

Comment: I tried using  line.decode('utf-8').encode('iso-8859-1') , but it says AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'

Also here is a sample of some lines I just pulled out with the unicodes 
Gotterd%C3%A4mmerung

Gurmukh%C4%AB alphabet
Hez%C3%A2rfen Ahmed Celebi
Hrad%C4%8Dany
Thich Nh%E1%BA%A5t H%E1%BA%A1nh
La%E1%B9%85k%C4%81vat%C4%81ra S%C5%ABtra
Hu%E1%BA%BF

http://pastebin.com/wckCENCc
I posted a portion of it on pastebin, lines 89, 132 and 153

Comment: What do consider a real letter?

Comment: What I mean by real letter is for example c3 bf is' ÿ', but I just put 'y'
@schwobaseggl

Comment: @gelezko I added a small part of the file

Comment: This is the input: Gotterd%C3%A4mmerung and the output should be: Gotterd ämmerung, @pp_

Comment: Sorry, using python 3 @AnttiHaapala

Comment: Also your pathnames are wrong - you should *either* use `r''` strings *or* double \\, not both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you everyone, I ended up getting it to work. I had to install the unidecode module which took me forever to figure out cause I was running into pip and cmd prompt errors. After the package installed I added this line and it worked.

```
line = cleanup(line)
line = unidecode(line)
```

I really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 3):

You could use [unidecode](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Unidecode) with [urllib.parse.unquote](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html) :

```
In [8]: from unidecode import  unidecode

In [9]: from urllib.parse import unquote

In [10]: unidecode(unquote("Gotterd%C3%A4mmerung"))
Out[10]: 'Gotterdammerung'
```

`unidecode` will convert the non ascii characters to their ascii equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`urllib.parse.unquote`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.unquote). It assumes UTF-8 by default, but in case there are also urls from other codecs among there, you can use some autodetection:

```
from urllib.parse import unquote

def cleanup(url):
    try:
        return unquote(url, errors='strict')
    except UnicodeDecodeError:
        return unquote(url, encoding='latin-1')
```

and `B%E1%BA%A3o %C4%90%E1%BA%A1i` was the last emperor of Vietnam:

```
>>> cleanup('B%E1%BA%A3o %C4%90%E1%BA%A1i')
'Bảo Đại'
```

---

If you want to convert these to the ASCII equivalents, you can use the [`unidecode`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Unidecode):

```
>>> unidecode.unidecode('Bảo Đại')
'Bao Dai'
```

Answer (score -1):

As far as my understanding goes, this is URL encoded i.e encoding the characters so that you can pass as parameter to server.

Use `unquote_plus()` from urllib:

```
s1 = u'B%E1%BA%A3o %E1%BA%A1i'
print urllib.unquote_plus(s1)
```

Output:

```
Báº£o áº¡i
```

Comment: I tried this, got invalid syntax error, tried other methods too and still same error @VarunJoshi